# How to detect HTML email input validation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Similarly as to when you can detect wether an input element with a `required` attribute was correctly validated, writing the following code:

```
if($('input').attr('required')) {
   alert(1);
}
```

How can I check if an input of `type='email'` was a valid entry?

EDIT:

I am not asking about how can I validate the input by comparing it to regex.

When you set the input type attribute to 'email', the submitted string has to have a proper format (it needs to contain '@' symbol and have a proper ending) because otherwise you won't be able to submit the form. What I want to achieve is to prevent the default action of form submit and check what is the state of that email input validation similarly as to when you can check if the required input was provided.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is your desired result?

Comment: maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I have completely no idea on how to catch the result of email format validation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: @Sysix, my question is different. I don't want to validate the email in my javascript by comparing the input to regex. I want to catch the result of the built-in form validation for email type input.

Comment: @manjii the first answer has a good example with user inputs :)

Comment: @Sysix but that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Input's have a [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)(IE 10+, Safari 10.0.03+) that can be used to check validity, ie `if(!element.validity.valid)`, is this what you were meaning?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Finally! That is more accurate although I tried it and it doesn't work. I get an error on the browser console saying "Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined".

Comment: @PatrickEvans and this is the code I used: `if($('input[type=email]').validity.valid) {
      alert('tru');
    }`

Comment: validity is not a jQuery property, it is a DOM property. So you need to access it from the actual DOM object, ie `document.querySelector('.input-email').validity.valid` or `$('.input-email')[0].validity.valid`, or `$('.input-email').prop('validity').valid`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Your last answer worked great! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To check the native browser input validation, use the [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) object that is on the element object.

It provides a few properties to test certain aspects like `typeMismatch` that is a boolean describing if the value of the input is a valid syntax for a type (url,email).

```
var input = document.getElementById('yourInput');
if(input.validity.typeMismatch){
   console.log('Input is not valid type');
}
```

To check general validity you can just check against `valid`

```
var input = document.getElementById('yourInput');
if(!input.validity.valid){
   console.log('Input is not valid');
}
```

If using jQuery simply get access to the actual element object, or use jQuery's prop() method to get to the ValidityState object

```
var input = jQuery('input');
//input[0].validity.valid 
//input.get(0).validity.valid etc
if( input.prop('validity').valid ){
  console.log('Valid input');
}
```

Note also that a couple of pseudo css classes are also provided. `:invalid` and `:valid` if needing to provide validation styling

```
:invalid {
  border:1px solid red;
}

:valid {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

Demo

```js
var email = $('#email'),
    num   = $('#anumber');
 
email.on('input',()=>{
  if(email.prop('validity').typeMismatch){
    console.log('Invalid email syntax');
  }
});
num.on('input',()=>{
  if(num.prop('validity').stepMismatch){
    console.log('Invalid number step');
  }
});
```

```css
:valid {
  border:1px solid green;
}
:invalid {
  border:1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Try Email">
<br>
<input id="anumber" step=10 type="number" placeholder="Try a number">
<br>
<input id="arequired" type="text" placeholder="Try a required" required>
```